# Setting default checkbox value in Objective-C?

Tags: checkbox, nsbutton

Okay, this one's making me feel stupid...

I'm a feature film editor who's recently started teaching myself Objective-C after many years away from coding. I think the last code I wrote was in Cobol, if that gives you any indication.

Anyway, I've recently written a small utility to take an edit decision list from Avid Media Composer and parse it for user-specified markers to automatically generate a sub-caption file. It's useful, it saves me a great amount of time, and it works.

I built my GUI in interface builder.

Now I'm interested in adding a small bit of functionality to my app, and I'd like to simply use a checkbox to ask the user if they'd like to use this functionality, ie: if it's checked, then do this.

I can add a checkbox using interface builder and I can check the status of it. My stupid noob question is: how do I set the checkbox to default to "Off" instead of "On" as interface builder seems to do automatically?

Thanks in advance for any quidance on this.

Chris Conlee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on [UISwitch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/on) says:

```
[mySwitch setOn:NO];
```

In Interface Builder, select your switch and in the Attributes inspector you'll find State which can be set to on or off.

Comment: Okay, well that didn't make me feel any smarter, but at least it quickly solved the problem I'd spent hours trying to sort out. Thanks, and have a happy New Year.